# how to assign thymeleaf variable to a tag value

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" >
    <option value="${item}"> something </option>
</c:forEach>
```

How can i do this in thymeleaf?

I've tried something like this:

```
<option th:each="item:${list}" value="${item}">  some product $ </option>
```

but it uses ${item} like a simple text "${item}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<option th:each="item:${list}" th:value="${item}">  some product $ </option>
```

You may just be missing the th: prefix for the value attribute.

Comment: i'm just new to thymeleaf, thanks a lot, ot's working perfect now.